# How to get all records in inherited_resources collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, inherited-resources

How to list all records in a single page without pagination. Now I didn't use limit to fetch selected records, but it returns only 20 records in a page.

How to remove limit from my query to retrieve all records?

UPDATE

```
def collection
 @users ||= apply_scopes(User).where(status: 'ACTIVE').order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).includes(:replies)
end
```

Comment: No code? I never heard of this 20 records limit

Comment: I don't want to include limit and offset in my active-record query.

Comment: By default, you should get all the records in the database without any limit. Are any of your scopes in User limiting the records?